# Get video height width from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've uploaded some video in s3. Now I want to get the height and width of the video from s3.

I'm using node js server. But not getting any api to get the height and width of the uploaded video.

I got one api to get the metadata of the video, but it doesn't return then height and width.

Is there any available api to get this details?

Comment: Height and width are internal details of the video. S3 metadata is metadata about tbe storage of the object, plus anything custom you've added. I suggest that you add metadata with the height and width, potentially when uploading. Another possibility would be to use the byte range S3 API to retrieve this metadata without having to read tbe whole object, but this would rely on it it being stored at a predictable address inside the objects.

Comment: I meant to say, "S3 byte range APi".